# c++ objected oriented dictionary program

Tags: c++, object

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3d2f3ba0c602c1427d0e43cb7e2030be
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f9c3e4bad3ac718053c8674081b6a172

I'm trying to make a program that will add a word to a dicitonary file called A.txt, B.txt, etc. I have tried to make all of the code for the addaword part but I got a strange error after fixing all of the smaller errors ( expected ;/}). I get [this error](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d70e03742b97e9fd5b374ae94abee588) after trying to compile it and run the CheckingForAddingAWord. I have not yet come across an error like this and I couldn't find a solution online. Thanks for the help!

Comment: please add your `main.cpp`, are you perhaps `#include`ing `"dictionary.cpp"`?

Comment: This was it. I used Dictionary.cpp instead of Dictionary.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This excerpt of the error message is quite clear:

```
In function `Dictionary::Dictionary()':
Dictionary.cpp: multiple definition of `Dictionary::Dictionary()'
main.cpp: first defined here
```

You are defining the constructor of the Dictionary class twice - once in Dictionary.cpp and then again in Main.cpp.  It is almost as if you are defining the constructor in the header file but outside the class definition - you should have any function that is part of the class defined inside the class OR outside the class in ONE cpp source file.  You would need to edit your question with all the source code to be sure.